# draw in an eclipse rcp view?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, jung, zest

I need to draw some circles and nodes (according to their (x,y) coordinates) in an rcp view. I think Zest is not appropriate or my application (the nodes can be moved, no coordinates..) I did my best to use jung, but  always got problems... so I decided to plot them using SWT "shapes". however, when I draw a circle and then resize the view (a new editor appears so the view is smaller) I miss the circle (doesn't appear)...
 I really need you help to know which is the best way to do my application? and if you too got problems using jung? 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many ways to this...

Apart from ZEST and Jung, you also have GMF and Graphitti, though these both can be considered overkill for a small project.

Last, but not least, you have SWT - as you also note - based on a `Canvas`. For an example on how to use this see the [SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#cancas) - specially  [paint a circle in a canvas](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet245.java)
 .

Comment: Thanks, but even when I use SWT Snippets, I get a lot of problems, with the "paint a circle in a canvas" example, I get an SWT exception: invalid thread access... :(

Comment: Hmm, I don't get this on OSX, Windows or Linux for this snippet. In general, all manipulations of SWT related widgets and objects _must_ occur in the SWT thread. See `Display.asyncExec(...)` for more information.